#  selenium RC and Flow control

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

Currently I am working on selenium IDE, now I need to switch to selenium RC. I have downloaded  selenium server.But I really don't know how to proceed further. Even I am not able to start server from command prompt. I have used C:\Selenium RC\selenium-server\jave -jar selenium-server.jar, but it struck in between and not proceeding further..
I am looking for language java or PHP.

Let me know how should I move further for successful execution of scripts by using selenium RC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: save a test suite in Selenium IDE (`File > Save Test Suite`). You should generate test suite - it will contain information about test cases (which, of course, should also be saved (`File > Save Test Case`)).
Then you are ready for testing with Selenium RC.
Try it with below command:
`java -jar path/to/selenium-server-standalone.jar -htmlsuite "*firefox" "http://google.com" "path/to/your/testsuite1" "path/to/result.html"`
`result.html` - this file will be generated during/after execution.
Be sure that name of browser, URL and paths to test suite and result file are in the quotation marks.

Comment: Thank you faramka, its working  :).But can i run scripts in PHP/ java format on command prompt?also 1 more thing, it is not supporting conditional statements.Currently it is giving error as Unknown command: &apos;gotoIf&apos;

Answer (score 0):

I am using Selenium with PHPUnit. I have got class called, lets say, `somethingTest` (test classes must have '*Test*' at the end of their names) and extended `PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase`. This class contains several test cases as methods (e.g. function `testSomeMethod1()` - '*test*' at the beginning).
And I run it by command:

```
phpunit somethingTest.php
```

As to the second thing:

> Unknown command: gotoIf

You should load gotoif extension by adding to the execution command something like:

```
-userExtensions path/to/extension-file
```

This indicates a JavaScript file that will be loaded into Selenium.

Comment: I will try for PHPUnit as you suggested, for extension should i used like this - java -jar selenium-server.jar -userExtension E:\Selenium\goto_sel_ide.js -multiwindow -htmlSuite "*firefox" "http://www.google.com" "C:\Selenium_Scripts\login\login.html"  "C:\Selenium_Scripts\results.html" ??Or am i wrong?

Comment: And does it work? :) If not, try to put extension filename in quotation marks and write 'http://' before URL. And the URL is address of your site, not necessarily google. And why there is semicolon after URL in your command?

Comment: java -jar selenium-server.jar -userExtension "C:\Selenium_Scripts\goto_sel_ide.js" -multiwindow -htmlSuite "*firefox" "http://184.73.175.93/LCPK/us/" "C:\Selenium_Scripts\login\login.html" "C:\Selenium_Scripts\results.html" i have tried this one, but getting same error..:(  :(

Comment: and i have added HTTP to URL, but it is not showing here. And also semicolon is not there

Comment: gotoIf  | storedVars.var1 | true  --this is command where my scripts fails, and says unknown command

Comment: The parameter is '-userExtensions' - not '-userExtension'. Check this http://www.seleniumwiki.com/software-testing/using-user-extensions-with-selenium-rc/ And login.html is test suite or test case?

Comment: every-time I am getting different things, now got this --java -jar selenium-server.jar -userExtensions goto_sel_ide.js -multiwindow -htmlSuite "*firefox" "http://184.73.175.93/LCPK/us/" "C
:\Selenium_Scripts\login\login.html" "C:\Selenium_Scripts\results.html"
Mar 29, 2012 12:24:27 PM org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher main
INFO: Launching a standalone server
User extensions file MUST be called "user-extensions.js": C:\Selenium RC\selenium-server\goto_sel_ide.js

Comment: java -jar C:\Selenium RC\selenium-server\selenium-server.jar -userExtensions "C:\Selenium RC\selenium-server\goto_sel_ide.js" -htmlSuite "*firefox" "184.73.175.93/LCPK/us/" "C:\Selenium_Scripts\login\login.html" "C:\Selenium_Scripts\results.html"

Comment: sorry to say dear, but still not working  :( error-User extensions file MUST be called "user-extensions.js": C:\Selenium RC\selenium-server\goto_sel_ide.js

Comment: OK, Marc. It is a bit weird, but try to change the name of your extension for 'user-extensions.js'.

Comment: frankly speaking, nothing is working fine..tried everything what you told..now m totally frustrated

Answer (score 0):

If you choose Java to write code, a better approach would be using an IDE like Eclipse. Once you link the JARs and import them in your Java classes you can write your code quickly and efficiently. On top of that, Ecplise has lot of plugins for testing software like Junit, TestNG's to help you create better test suites. Not to mention a Java IDE is always helpful in debugging test code. Here is a tutorial on how to setup Eclipse with Selenium: http://selftechy.com/2011/05/31/setting-up-selenium-with-eclipse

Hope it helps.