# How to run add ons in firefox webdriver by Selenium RC?

Tags: firefox, batch-file, automation, firefox-addon, selenium-rc

I want to execute some add-ons on FireFox webdriver from my default profile in order to use them when I execute testing by Selenium RC (TestRunner).

I've tried to use:

> -firefoxProfileTempalte "C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\akjpu67f.default"

And:

> firefox.exe -install-global-extension "C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\akjpu67f.default\extensions\flow-control@dave.hunt.xpi"

Inline the third line in the code below (BAT file),
but it doesn't work :/

```
cd C:\automation\screenshots\
del *.png
@echo off
java -jar C:\automation\selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar -htmlSuite "*firefox C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" "C:\automation\emailSanity.html" "C:\automation\testing_results.html"
%SendKeys% "echo off{ENTER}"
start firefox.exe "file://c:\automation\testing_results.html" "file://c:\automation\screenshots\images_dif.html"
%SendKeys% "echo off{ENTER}"
REM start C:\automation\sendEmail.bat
REM %SendKeys% "echo off{ENTER}"
exit
```

Please assist!!

Thanks a lot,

Idan.

Answer (score 3):

Start your Firefox with following call on your BAT file;

> firefox.exe -install-global-extension "C:\Temp\extension-file.xpi"

Comment: End of this: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe`. Edit your BAT file.

Comment: Thanks again,
but there an exception on loading.

This is the edited BAT line:

java -jar C:\automation\selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar -firefoxProfileTempalte "C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\akjpu67f.default" -htmlSuite "*firefox C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -install-global-extension "C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\akjpu67f.default\extensions\flow-control@dave.hunt.xpi" "C:\automation\emailSanity.html" "C:\automation\testing_results.html"

Comment: What about this; `"*firefox C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe -install-global-extension 'C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\akjpu67f.default\extensi‌​ons\flow-control@dave.hunt.xpi'"`

Comment: OK, I've tried this: `java -jar C:\automation\selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar "*firefox C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe -install-global-extension 'C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\akjpu67f.default\extensi‌​‌​ons\flow-control@dave.hunt.xpi'" -htmlSuite "*firefox C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" "C:\automation\emailSanity.html" "C:\automation\testing_results.html"`
but it doesn't execute the add-on :/
@Turcia Please your help again, Thanks!

Comment: Does add-on activated when you type `C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe -install-global-extension 'C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\akjpu67f.default\extensi‌​‌​‌​ons\flow-control@dave.hunt.xpi'` on command line? (You need to escape space characters on path)

Comment: Yes, but it's opened the FF as regular with all the add-ons inside. @Turcia

Comment: I got it. May be, it's not the solution we're looking for. I'll try when I switch to Windows machine.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
Actually, this is similar to my problem:

[selenium-rc-and-flow-control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9902304/selenium-rc-and-flow-control)

But less complex.

Answer (score 1):

You can run Firefox with addons using the following code:

```
FireFoxProfile ffProfile = new FireFoxProfile();
File ffExtension= new File("<path>"/addin.xpi");
ffProfile .addExtension(ffExtension);

WebDriver webDriver = new FireFoxDriver(ffProfile );
```

Comment: Thanks Jamie,
Can you please guide me how to use this code? I want to run this by BAT file.
thanks!

Comment: Hello Idan, I think I misread the question unfortunaly, when you state Selenium Runner do you mean the Firefox Selenium GUI?

Comment: No, I meant to Selenium TestRunner (http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC126862.gif).
Anyway, I've tried to save your code in javaScript and execute it by BAT file. Is it possible?
Second question - Can I write a couple of add ons inside the "file ffExtension" line?
thanks.